# Union of Ranges not storing the values of all the concerned cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have seen multiple threads on similar questions, but didn't find a satisfactory answer.

On the first row of an otherwise blank sheet, I have 1, 2, 3, 4 on the first five cells, with a blank cell in the middle. I want to paste these numbers, contiguously, on the line below.

```
Sub test()

   Dim originCells As Range
   
   Set originCells = Union(Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 2)), _
   Range(Cells(1, 4), Cells(1, 5)))

   Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 4)) = originCells.Value

End Sub
```

I'm getting 1, 2, #NA, #NA. The Union is functionning properly, as I've tested it with a simple

```
originCells.Select
```

So the problem is that the last two values are somehow not stored?

I can't believe there isn't an answer to this simple problem?

Thanks

Comment: Non-contiguous ranges (i.e. ranges that have more than one `Area`) aren't as straightforward. One option is to loop the areas.

Comment: You have created a range with two `Areas`.  You cannot equate a single area array with a multi area array, without iterating the areas.  You can copy paste: `originCells.Copy Cells(2,1)` but equating value arrays cannot be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by BigBen and Scott Craner non contiguous ranges can't be directly equated. You will need to loop or copy to get the values into another range.

Looping:

```
Sub testloop()

    Dim originCells As Range
   
    Set originCells = Union(Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 2)), _
    Range(Cells(1, 4), Cells(1, 5)))
    Debug.Print originCells.Address
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    i = 0
    For Each cell In originCells
        Cells(2, 1).Offset(0, i).Value = cell.Value
        i = i + 1
    Next cell
    
End Sub
```

Copying:

```
Sub testcolumncopy()
    Dim originCells As Range
   
    Set originCells = Union(Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 2)), _
    Range(Cells(1, 4), Cells(1, 5)))
    Debug.Print originCells.Address
    originCells.Copy Cells(3, 1)
End Sub

Sub testrowcopy()
    Dim originCells As Range
   
    Set originCells = Union(Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 2)), _
    Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 2)))
    Debug.Print originCells.Address
    originCells.Copy Cells(4, 1)
End Sub
```

Note however that if both the row and column are offset in the unioned range then copy will error.

```
Sub badtestcopy()
    Dim originCells As Range
   
    Set originCells = Union(Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 2)), _
    Range(Cells(2, 5), Cells(2, 6)))
    Debug.Print originCells.Address
    originCells.Copy Cells(4, 1)
End Sub
```

So the safer bet is to loop unless you know that won't be the case.